# What is the code to resize a picturebox in c#?

Tags: c#, resize, size, picturebox

I'm only a beginner in C#, so simple answers would really help.

I'm trying to make a very simple game that detects a `MouseClick` on a `PictureBox` of size 50,50 (at the beginning of the game). After each successful MouseClick on the PictureBox (which has a blue `BackgroundImage`), I want to change to `Size` of the PictureBox so that it is 1 pixel smaller in `Width` and `Height`. I will then have the PictureBox move to a random location (which I already know how to do, so no help is needed for that part).

I think it may have something to do with `picturebox.Resize` but I'm not very sure.

Comment: would be nice if you would leave a comment at the answer and or mark it as accepted :D

Comment: Very late, but here you go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a total general question you should look it up in the internet and dont ask it here..
btt:

```
Size size = new Size(100,100);
pictureBox1.Size = size;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspxh

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.size.aspx

in your case this would be your code:

```
Size size = pictureBox1.Size;
size.Height--;
size.Width--;
pictureBox1.Size = size;
```

or just:

```
pictureBox1.Height--;
pictureBox1.Width--;
```

or for the cool ones:

```
private int size = 50;
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    size--;
    pictureBox1.Height = pictureBox1.Width = size;
}
```

resp.:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Height = pictureBox1.Width = pictureBox1.Width - 1;
}
```

Comment: You also need to make sure the PictureBox is not docked on all sides (FILL).  This will prevent your change in size from taking effect.

Answer (score 1):

This should work..

```
int newSize = 50; //Global variable
```

**PictureBox1_Click** Event

```
pictureBox1.Size = new Size(newSize--,newSize--);
```